# Why do contents flow under a fixed DIV?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a fixed DIV. The page contents should be displayed after the DIV, but they are under the DIV - partially hidden by it. How can I avoid this?

Here is the DIV's style:

```
#top_div {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Because your using fixed. [Read up about fixed and what it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Take it away and it will be fine.

Comment: I did, and since I seem to be less smart than you, a real help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have put an answer up to explain a little better. If you want move help please tell me what you want the div to do. As I have just answered your question.

Comment: Absolute and fixed positioned elements are removed from the natural flow of the page, only relative or static elements will have other elements flow around them. Add `padding-top:20%` to your content div (it will still go under the fixed div when you start scrolling though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we do not know your entire code, but if it is like

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="fixed">fixed</div>
   //a lot of html code here
</div>
```

put some top-padding to the .container div, padding equal to the height of the fixed div

Comment: also, maybe put it at least "position:absolute", because it will block the page view when you scroll down... after all, the role of a fixed div it TO block the page view (look at the ads nightmare)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

[Fixed Div](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6Q9w4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>Fixed div</div>Can we see this?
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: fixed;
}
```

---

[Now without fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6Q9w4/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>Not Fixed div</div>Can we see this?
```

**CSS:**

```
div {

}
```

Just to show you what the difference is. You can see the `div` as `position: fixed` is sitting on top of the content after. The `div` will stay in that place always on screen. Thats what fixed does. You do not want this (I don't think as you didn't explain what you want it to do) so just remove it.

Example of `position:fixed` working on a page that can scroll, you will see it is always on the screen.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6Q9w4/3/)

Do not used fixed as this is what causes the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you. What I want is a fixed header, which does not cover the page conents. Is it possible? Any other solution? I don't want to use a frame, unless it is the only solution.

Comment: @Federico Im not 100% sure what you mean but you may want to look into  sticky header. Check [this out](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/) demo of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/show/)

Comment: I've used another solution (look at the answer I chosen). But sticky may be interesting, except that it doesn't seem to be standard. Is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: @Federico Your saying fixed to me but you mean just sitting at the top (and when scrolling it goes off screen)? The other answer does not make sense for fixed. There is not need to have absolute at all if you want it just sitting at the top. And yes that is supported by all browser's.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to achieve this (http://jsfiddle.net/6Q9w4/8/)

```
.header {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #4679bd;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```